# Show DISTINCT user_id ONLY if record column matches threeconditions

Tags: mysql, sql

Fairly new to MySQL and I'm struggling with a query for table of data I'm trying to filter through. What I'd like to be able to do is identify the user_id's only where a set of conditions is met on the record column.

**Example**

Return a SINGLE user_id of each of the users that hold ALL of the records 1, 2 & 3.

```
user_id     record       
---------------------
1000        1
1001        1  
1002        1
1003        1
1004        1   
1000        2
1000        3 
1002        2
1002        3
```

The ideal output in this example would be...

```
user_id
-------
1000
1002
```

I've tried quite a few variants using HAVING, COUNT and IN but I never seem to get the correct output and I think I'm starting to confuse myself. Anyone that could help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

Do aggregation :

```
select user_id
from t 
where record in (1, 2, 3)
group by user_id
having count(*) = 3; -- Use distinct inside function in case of duplicate records
```

If you don't know what the records are, then you can do :

```
select user_id
from t 
group by user_id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct record) from t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING Clause with a query to distinctly count all user_id values :

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM t 
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct record) FROM t );
```